# Dafny iterator on heap fails to ensure Valid()

Tags: dafny

I have a class that allocates an iterator on the heap and calls `MoveNext()` on that iterator. I want to prove that if `MoveNext()` returns `true`, `Valid()` holds for the iterator.

```
iterator Iter()
{}

class MyClass
{
    var iter : Iter;

    constructor ()
    {
        iter := new Iter();
    }
    method next() returns (more : bool)
    requires iter.Valid();
    modifies iter, iter._new, iter._modifies;
    {
        more := iter.MoveNext();
        // This assertion fails:
        assert more ==> iter.Valid();
    }
}
```

I took a look at the output of `/rprint`, and the method `MoveNext()` contains `ensures more ==> this.Valid()`, which seems to imply my desired assertion. If I change iter to be locally allocated within the method `next()`, then Dafny verifies the assertion.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem is that nothing is known about what's in `iter._new` and `iter._modifies`. If `this` is in one of those sets, then `this.iter` may have changed during the call to `MoveNext()`.

This body for `next()` confirms what I just said:

```
var i := iter;
more := iter.MoveNext();
assert i == iter;  // this assertion fails
assert more ==> iter.Valid();
```

So, under the assumption `more`, `Valid()` does still hold of the iterator, but the iterator may no longer referenced by `iter`:

```
more := iter.MoveNext();
assert more ==> old(iter).Valid();  // this holds
```

Probably the way you want to solve this problem is to add a precondition to `next()`:

```
method next() returns (more : bool)
  requires iter.Valid()
  requires this !in iter._new + iter._modifies  // add this precondition
  modifies iter, iter._new, iter._modifies
{
  more := iter.MoveNext();
  assert more ==> iter.Valid();  // this now verifies
}
```

Rustan